# We found this is it mold?

Tags: mold

[image]

We had a water leak about two months ago and since then I have been sick. We have a mold specialist coming out but they couldn’t come for two weeks. We peeled the carpet back to find this...

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It's hard to say from one picture, and I'm no expert, but that doesn't look like mold to me, as it's granular.

Answer (score 1):

That appears to just be the broken down remains of rubberized carpet padding. If you look on the tack strip (the little strip with the nails in it that holds the carpet in place), there appear to be larger pieces of it still embedded on the strip, probably from a previous carpet installation that was removed sloppilly years ago. That's not to say you don't have mold somewhere, but that's not mold.